# Message MD5 generation

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

for my ROS project I need to get MD5 checksum of messages from their .msg files. Following documentation this should be quite simple. I just get the .msg file with:

- comments and whitespace removed;
- package names of dependencies
  removed;
- constants reordered ahead of other declarations;
- MD5 text of dependency concatenated,

and calculate MD5 on it.

So, for std_msgs/String, the MD5 should be calculated on:

stringdata

and the MD5 be:

cb6d1e784571bbf6f218efb801675fb6

Instead the generated message in my Hydro installation has MD5 (rosmsg md5 std_msgs/String):

992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1

Can one help me to understand what is wrong?

Thanks a lot
Alessandro

### EDITED

See https://github.com/ros/genmsg/blob/indigo-devel/src/genmsg/gentools.py and https://github.com/ros/genmsg/blob/indigo-devel/src/genmsg/msgs.py

Thanks to gvdhorn!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201427/message-md5-generation/) by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not a real answer, but have you perhaps considered using [genmsg](https://github.com/ros/genmsg.git) for this? See [genmsg/test/test_genmsg_gentools.py](https://github.com/ros/genmsg/blob/indigo-devel/test/test_genmsg_gentools.py) for some examples.

---

Edit: just to be complete:

```
msg_context = genmsg.msg_loader.MsgContext.create_default()
full_type_name = genmsg.gentools.compute_full_type_name(package_name, os.path.basename(input_file))
spec = genmsg.msg_loader.load_msg_from_file(msg_context, input_file, full_type_name)
search_path = genmsg.command_line.includepath_to_dict(include_path)
genmsg.msg_loader.load_depends(msg_context, spec, search_path)

md5sum = genmsg.gentools.compute_md5(msg_context, spec)
```

Mostly creative copy/paste from the `genmsg` package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-09**:
Update: `rosmg md5 $pkg/$msg` should also work.